# PHP: Readfile() works fine at localhost but not at server

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP. Here is my problem. I tried using readfile to download a pdf file and it works on localhost but on the online server well it prints the file contents with strange characters. I tried other codes but the same problem persists. I researched for several days and found nothing conclusive. So please help me.
Here is everything I tried:

```
            $chemin = dirname(__FILE__,3)."/resultats_examens/".$Open;
            $fileName = basename($chemin);
            $filePath = $chemin;
            if(!empty($fileName) && file_exists($filePath)){
                header('Content-type: application/pdf'); 
                    
                header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $fileName . '"'); 
                    
                header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary'); 
                    
                header('Accept-Ranges: bytes'); 
                    
                // Lire le fichier
                @readfile($filePath);  }
```

I tried everything too :

```
                //Stocker le nom du fichier dans une variable
                //for any file
                $file = fopen($filePath, 'rb');
                if ( $file !== false ) {
                    fpassthru($file);
                    fclose($file);
                }
                //for any file, if fpassthru() is disabled
                $file = fopen($filePath, 'rb');
                if ( $file !== false ) {
                    while ( !feof($file) ) {
                        echo fread($file, 4096);
                    }
                    fclose($file);
                }
                //for small files;
                //this should not be used for large files, as it loads whole file into memory
                $data = file_get_contents($filePath);
                if ( $data !== false ) {
                    echo $data;
                }
```

And here is what is displayed on the screen:

```
  %PDF-1.7

  4 0 obj
  (Identity)
  endobj
  5 0 obj
  (Adobe)
  endobj
  8 0 obj
  <<
  /Filter /FlateDecode
  /Length 80044
  /Type /Stream
  >>
  stream
  x��   `T��?~�[f��o&��$3��L C$�$�
```

Comment: If you download the exact file from the server does it still work locally? You might have scrambled the encoding somewhere if not.

Comment: that's what I said, when I put the code on the server, it doesn't work, it's the content of the file that is displayed. and no error message.

Comment: Good. So why all the examples worked very well in localhost with Wampserver and then on the online server it displayed this

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've got a couple of problems. Here is my recipe for sending PDF files for download. I would try adding these to your code incrementally and see what solves the problem (don't just cargo-cult the whole thing).

```php
<?php
$filePath = '/path/to/file.pdf';
$fileTime = filemtime($filePath);

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($filePath).'"');
header('Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, j M Y H:i:s T', $fileTime));
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filePath));

ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($filePath);
```

Comment: Thank you but I have already used all that but still displays the same thing. and yet everything works fine in localhost.
On the Dreamhost server I'm using the download never starts but displays content with strange characters

Comment: Look a the actual headers returned in your browser. Anything look strange? If you're relying on mime_content_type to set the MIME type, double check that it's actually returning application/pdf.

Comment: I wonder if there is something I need to activate on the server. I understand nothing

Comment: it's always the same display

Comment: I have already tried your code several times, it is always the same message

Comment: Did you look at the actual headers? This code works, you've got something else going on.

Comment: As Rob has already suggested twice, look at the headers.  You can use this site for instance.   https://dnschecker.org/server-headers-check.php  And heres an article on how to use the browser to look at them.  https://packetpushers.net/viewing-http-headers-using-browser-tools/

Answer (score 0):

It is resolved. the problem is that I had used Ajax to pass variables to the download file.
now i used window.location.href to pass the variables and open the download file. it works locally and on the server

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).